# Empty elements as dots in matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to create a determinant (vmatrix) as shown in this picture.[image] So, I wrote a simple LaTEX file for testing purposes as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{vmatrix}
                0     &\cdot &\cdot &0     &a_{1} \alpha_{1}+ \cdots +k_{1} \alpha_{n} &\cdot &\cdot &a_{1} \kappa_{1}+ \cdots +k_{1} \kappa_{n} \\
                \cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot                                      &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \\
                0     &\cdot &\cdot &0     &a_{n} \alpha_{1}+ \cdots +k_{n} \alpha_{n} &\cdot &\cdot &a_{n} \kappa_{1}+ \cdots +k_{n} \kappa_{n} \\
                -1    &\cdot &\cdot &0     &\alpha_{1}                                 &\cdot &\cdot &\kappa_{1} \\
                \cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot                                      &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \\
                0     &\cdot &\cdot &-1    &\alpha_{n}                                 &\cdot &\cdot &\kappa_{n}
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

When the above file gets compiled with TeXLive on a Linux desktop computer, it produces the following ugly result:[image] I thought using `\hdotsfor{}` for the horizontal line, but the spacing between the dots is too close. If there is a simple way to tell `\hdotsfor{}` to skip every dot, I believe that would do. However, perhaps someone here knows a much better way.

Comment: `\hdotsfor` has an optional argument which is a multiplier for the amount of space between consecutive dots, so you could try `\hdotsfor[2]{<number of rows>}`. I'm not sure if it'd look good though, since they wouldn't align with the dots in your first row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems a good approximation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\widedots}{%
  .\cleaders\hbox to 2\tabcolsep{\hss.\hss}\hfill.%
  \hspace*{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\ak}[2]{%
  \makebox[14\tabcolsep][s]{$\displaystyle a_{#2}#1_1+\dots+k_{#2}#1_n$}%
}
\begin{vmatrix}
 0 & . & . &  0 & \ak{\alpha}{1} & . & . & \ak{\kappa}{1} \\
 . & . & . &  . & \widedots      & . & . & \widedots      \\
 0 & . & . &  0 & \ak{\alpha}{n} & . & . & \ak{\kappa}{n} \\
-1 & . & . &  0 & \alpha_{1}     & . & . & \kappa_{1}     \\
 . & . & . &  . & \widedots      & . & . & \widedots      \\
 0 & . & . & -1 & \alpha_{n}     & . & . & \kappa_{n}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The value `14\tabcolsep` has been determined by first looking at the entries at their natural width.

Even better than the original if we make `-1` to hide its width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\widedots}{%
  .\cleaders\hbox to 2\tabcolsep{\hss.\hss}\hfill.%
  \hspace*{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\ak}[2]{%
  \makebox[14\tabcolsep][s]{$\displaystyle a_{#2}#1_1+\dots+k_{#2}#1_n$}%
}
\newcommand{\?}{\makebox[0pt]{$-1$}}
\begin{vmatrix}\mspace{8mu}
\begin{matrix}
 0 & . & . &  0 & \ak{\alpha}{1} & . & . & \ak{\kappa}{1} \\
 . & . & . &  . & \widedots      & . & . & \widedots      \\
 0 & . & . &  0 & \ak{\alpha}{n} & . & . & \ak{\kappa}{n} \\
\? & . & . &  0 & \alpha_{1}     & . & . & \kappa_{1}     \\
 . & . & . &  . & \widedots      & . & . & \widedots      \\
 0 & . & . & \? & \alpha_{n}     & . & . & \kappa_{n}
\end{matrix}\mspace{3mu}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\dots` and `\hdotsfor`:

```
\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\ak}[2]{a_{#2}#1_1+\dots+k_{#2}#1_n}
\begin{vmatrix}
 0 & \dots &  0 & \ak{\alpha}{1} & \dots & \ak{\kappa}{1} \\
\hdotsfor{6} \\
 0 & \dots &  0 & \ak{\alpha}{n} & \dots & \ak{\kappa}{n} \\
-1 & \dots &  0 & \alpha_{1}     & \dots & \kappa_{1}     \\
\hdotsfor{6} \\
 0 & \dots & -1 & \alpha_{n}     & \dots & \kappa_{n}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I may not be able to decipher how your code works, it looks like the one with the capability of hiding the with of -1 fits my need. I have a feeling after perusing your code, I will understand better. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to manually put dots with some horizontal space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{vmatrix}
                0     &\cdot &\cdot &0     &a_{1} \alpha_{1}+ \cdots +k_{1} \alpha_{n} &\cdot &\cdot &a_{1} \kappa_{1}+ \cdots +k_{1} \kappa_{n} \\
                \cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \hfil \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot                               &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \hfil \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot  \\
                0     &\cdot &\cdot &0     &a_{n} \alpha_{1}+ \cdots +k_{n} \alpha_{n} &\cdot &\cdot &a_{n} \kappa_{1}+ \cdots +k_{n} \kappa_{n} \\
                -1    &\cdot &\cdot &0     &\alpha_{1}                                 &\cdot &\cdot &\kappa_{1} \\
                \cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \hfil \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot                                      &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \hfil \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot \hfil \cdot  \\
                0     &\cdot &\cdot &-1    &\alpha_{n}                                 &\cdot &\cdot &\kappa_{n}
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Honestly, I had never thought of using '\hfil'. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Defining two newcommands `\twodts` and `\fivedts` for empty columns and rows can simplify the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\twodts}{\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}$\cdot$&$\cdot$\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\fivedts}{\begin{tabular}{@{}*5{c}@{}}$\cdot$&$\cdot$&$\cdot$&$\cdot$&$\cdot$\end{tabular}}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{|cccccc|}
    0     & \twodts & 0     & a_1 \alpha_1+ \cdots +k_1 \alpha_n & \twodts & a_1 \kappa_1+ \cdots +k_1 \kappa_n \\
    \cdot & \twodts & \cdot & \fivedts                           & \twodts & \fivedts                           \\
    0     & \twodts & 0     & a_n \alpha_1+ \cdots +k_n \alpha_n & \twodts & a_n \kappa_1+ \cdots +k_n \kappa_n \\
    -1    & \twodts & 0     & \alpha_1                           & \twodts & \kappa_1                           \\
    \cdot & \twodts & \cdot & \fivedts                           & \twodts & \fivedts                           \\
    0     & \twodts & -1    & \alpha_n                           & \twodts & \kappa_n
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Update:**

You can easily adapt my answer to add six dots instead of five like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\def\twocdots{$\cdot$&$\cdot$}
\newcommand{\twodts}{\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}\twocdots\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\sixdts}{\begin{tabular}{@{}*6{c}@{}}\twocdots&\twocdots&\twocdots\end{tabular}}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{|cccccc|}
    0     & \twodts & 0     & a_1 \alpha_1+ \cdots +k_1 \alpha_n & \twodts & a_1 \kappa_1+ \cdots +k_1 \kappa_n \\
    \cdot & \twodts & \cdot & \sixdts                            & \twodts & \sixdts                            \\
    0     & \twodts & 0     & a_n \alpha_1+ \cdots +k_n \alpha_n & \twodts & a_n \kappa_1+ \cdots +k_n \kappa_n \\
    -1    & \twodts & 0     & \alpha_1                           & \twodts & \kappa_1                           \\
    \cdot & \twodts & \cdot & \sixdts                            & \twodts & \sixdts                            \\
    0     & \twodts & -1    & \alpha_n                           & \twodts & \kappa_n
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This looks pretty simple and good solution. Since there is still some gaps that seems to be able to put one more dot when using the `\fivedts' command, I wonder if this command can be modded to accommodate the gap. I tried to modify with a "\sixdots" and it does not work, unfortunately. Anyway, thank you too.

Comment: Please see my update for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be acceptable?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
           \begin{vmatrix}
            0     &\cdots &0     &a_{1} \alpha_{1}+ \cdots +k_{1} \alpha_{n} &\cdots     &a_{1} \kappa_{1}+ \cdots +k_{1} \kappa_{n} \\
            \vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots  &\vdots \\
            0     &\cdots & 0     &a_{n} \alpha_{1}+ \cdots +k_{n} \alpha_{n} &\cdots  &a_{n} \kappa_{1}+ \cdots +k_{n} \kappa_{n} \\
            -1    &\cdots &0     &\alpha_{1}  &\cdots &\kappa_{1} \\
            \vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots   &\ddots &\vdots \\
            0     &\cdots & -1    &\alpha_{n}  &\cdots &\kappa_{n}
    \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is I usually do and I don't think it will do for me. Sorry and I try to stick closer to the example I posted above. Anyway, thank you.